# Subquery returning only first row for all row

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a table named customer consisting of city column where the customer lived, service_code is the service customer paid for. I would like to show the cities where customer lived, number of customers in each cities and most preferred service in the city.

## Goal

I would like to show the city, how many customers in the city, the most preferred service in the city.

## customer table

```
id |  city  | service
1  |honkong | a
2  |la      | a
3  |la      | b
4  |hongkong| b
5  |taiwan  | a
6  |bangkok | b
7  |bangkok | d
...
```

## Code I've tried

```
   SELECT w_city
  ,count(w_city) as all
  , (select TOP 1 service_code from customer
        group by service_code
        order by count (service_code) desc) 
        AS favorit
 FROM customer
  group by w_city
```

## Problem

The w_city column and all works well but the problem come from favorit column which only showing the first right. all the rest are same as the first row for favorit column.

```
| w_city | all |favorit|
|hongkong| 100 | a
|la      | 40  | a
|taiwan  | 22  | a
|bangkok | 23  | a
```

## The result should be

```
| w_city | all |favorit|
|hongkong| 100 | a
|la      | 40  | b
|taiwan  | 22  | b
|bangkok | 23  | d
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: could you please provide some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need a correlated subquery :

```
SELECT w_city,
       COUNT(w_city) as all,
       (SELECT TOP 1 service_code
          FROM customer
         WHERE w_city = c.w_city
         GROUP BY service_code
         ORDER BY count(service_code) DESC ) AS favorit
  FROM customer c
 GROUP BY by w_city
```

Answer (score 1):

you trying join the service code in descending order, thus you need to join it via `row_number()`

```
Select t1.w_city, t1.all, t2.service_code from 
    (Select w_city
       ,count(w_city) as all   
       ,row_number() over (order by count(w_city) desc) as rn
     from customer
     group by w_city) t1
left join
     (select service_code
        ,row_number() over (order by count(service_code) desc) as rn 
      from customer
      group by service_code) t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

Comment: i put desc because i want to order it by the most chosen service in the city. i but i will try your suggestion soon, thank you for your reply